# maven generate custom parameters possible?

Tags: maven

I am using

mvn archetype:generate

I have a sub project named 'simple' that my archetype project uses as template

my archetype project lives in my local repo and acts on these commandline parameters

```
-DarchetypeGroupId=
-DarchetypeArtifactId=
-DarchetypeVersion=
-DarchetypeCatalog=local
```

I execute it as follows 
        mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.myplatform -DarchetypeArtifactId=myplatform-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=0.1-SNAPSHOT -DarchetypeCatalog=local

This is fine and works... I get a new project created.

I want to integrate two custom parameters to feed in HOST and PORT but I see no such parameters defined within the archetype:generate maven plugin

Can someone tell me how to operate and create two new parameters HOST and PORT ?

I wold like it to be done on the command line like the other parameters so I can reference it within my template project like ${hostId} ${portId}

Thanks

**
P.S. I saw -Darchetype.properties=../archetype.properties but would rather operate the commandline instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
META-INF/maven/archetype-metadata.xml   

<requiredProperties>
        <requiredProperty key="hostId">
          <defaultValue>localhost</defaultValue>
        </requiredProperty>
        <requiredProperty key="portId">
          <defaultValue>9011</defaultValue>
        </requiredProperty>
        <requiredProperty key="hibernateConnectionUrl">
          <defaultValue>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/psi?autoReconnect=true</defaultValue>
        </requiredProperty>     
        <requiredProperty key="property-without-default"/>
</requiredProperties>
```

Comment: Can someone elaborate on my answer? When I run this... the parameter is shown with a default assigned but maven does not actually allow the user to input an override.